# Rings where $ab=0$ for all elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups

Let $R$ be a ring, not necessarily unital, such that $ab=0$ for all $a,b\in R$. Suppose $R$ only has trivial right ideals. Is it true that $R$ has finite order? Are these rings special?

Comment: They are so far from being special that any abelian group $G$ can be turned into a ring with this property: simply define $ab=0$ for all $a,b \in G$.

Comment: Such rings are called "null-ring" in Germany. I do not know whether it is called "zero-ring" in Great Britain or America.

Comment: I believe zero-ring in America refers to the ring with 1 element. So, it's probably called something else here. I'm actually curious about whether these rings always have finite order.

Comment: They can have infinite order. Take an infinite abelian group $G$.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry, I forgot an extra restriction. $R$ only has trivial right ideals.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out.

Comment: example : a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra built on a commutative algebra ?

Answer (score 0):

Under these conditions, every Abelian subgroup is an ideal.

An element of infinite order generates  a copy of $\Bbb Z$, which obviously contains more copes of $\Bbb Z$ and more subgroups/ideals.

If an element has finite order which is a composite integer, it also contains proper subgroups. So a nonzero element must have prime order and generate the entire ring.